# Sqlite select statement from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables: `Products` and `CategoryProducts`.
`CategoryProducts` contains:

```
PrdID    Category
-----------------
```

`Products` contains:

```
PrdID   Barcode   Url
-----------------------
```

I have Product's Barcode value, for example 111111.

> Need to select all Products.Url with the same Category, as this item's
>   Category.

Having Products.PrdID, i can get all needed PrdID's from CategoryProducts like this:

```
select distinct c1.PrdID
from CategoryProduct_MM c1
where c1.CategoryID in (select c2.CategoryID
                        from CategoryProduct_MM c2
                        where c2.PrdID = 175)
```

Comment: Please clarify the question.  Do you need just one category to match?  All of them?  Some of them?

Comment: The best way to clarify this would be to provide some sample data with expected output.

Comment: @GordonLinoff just one. for example, if i have a product with Barcode = 42244, it has PrdID = 175 and Category = 4. I need to select all PrdID's with the same Category and get Url of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, this is what you want:

```
SELECT t.Url
FROM Products t
INNER JOIN CategoryProducts s
ON(s.PrdID = t.PrdID)
WHERE s.CategoryID = (select p.categoryID from CategoryProducts p
                      INNER JOIN Products f ON(p.prdID = f.prdID)
                      WHERE f.barcode =  42244)
```

Selects all the URLS , that their users are in the same category as PrdID ->175

Comment: Thank you, it gives me URLs. But i don't have PrdID. I have  Barcode -> 42244. It equals PrdID ->175 in Products table

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    p.url
FROM
    Products p
JOIN
    CategoryProducts cp ON cp.PrdID = p.id
// WHERE p.id = 175
GROUP BY p.url, p.Category
```

And if you need add comment query

Comment: That is not what he asked for

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT p.Url, p.PrdID
     FROM Products p 
JOIN CategoryProduct cp 
    ON p.PrdID = cp.PrdID 
JOIN 
Category c on c.id = cp.CategoryID AND cp.PrdID =175
```

// you need join table Category
Show me your Category table structure